# Override email_exists function

Tags: filters, pluggable

I am trying to override the email_exists function to modify the way it works slightly.  It is not listed as a pluggable function so I am unsure how to go about it.

I would like thef following to happen

- Somebody tries to register with an existing email address
- Wordpress detects that this is a duplicate
- Wordpress automatically assigns it a random email address instead

Can something be done with filters?

UPDATE - ---
I now have this in my functions file...

```
add_filter(
    'pre_user_email',
    'wpse163079_pre_user_email_example'
);
function wpse163079_pre_user_email_example(
    $user_email
) {
    if ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
        $user_email = 'randomemail3452345@example.com';
        return $user_email;
    } else {
        return $user_email;
    }
}
```

But this is not working, it still gives me the message that 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please login'

Comment: If you add what modification you had in mind, then it would be easier to help you, maybe there is another way to do what you want.

Comment: Good point, I have updated the original post with some more information on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Ok, this is a woocommerce error message, as you should be very well aware, third party plug-in questions are off topic.

Comment: I assumed WordPress was taking care of the registration functions, looks like this isn't the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* The reason this doesn't work for the OP is the use of woocommerce, otherwise, so in regards of core WordPress functionality, this should be working as described.

---

**Update:**

I assumed it is about emails on registration. Good thing you specified your needs. WordPress tries - several checks are performed - to add the new user with [`wp_insert_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) - [source: `user.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1596). There you have the filter [`pre_user_email`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1717), which you can use for your purpose.

The exemplary usage would be like this:

```
add_filter(
    'pre_user_email',
    'wpse163079_pre_user_email_example'
);
function wpse163079_pre_user_email_example(
    $user_email
) {
    if ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
        // code that generates the random email address
        // do not forget to check if the random one does exist
        // assign random address as new $user_email then
        return $user_email;
    } else {
        return $user_email;
    }
}
```

---

You can't override [`email_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/email_exists) as it isn't a pluggable function. But a look into the [source: `user.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1557) shows:

```
function email_exists( $email ) {
        if ( $user = get_user_by('email', $email) )
                return $user->ID;

       return false;
}
```

So `email_exists()` uses [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) - [source: `pluggable.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L144) -, which on the other hand is a pluggable function, so that one you could override. As you can see `get_user_by()` does look like this:

```
function get_user_by( $field, $value ) {
        $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value );

        if ( !$userdata )
                return false;

        $user = new WP_User;
        $user->init( $userdata );

        return $user;
}
```

So no hook - action or filter - you could use. But it shows that is mainly a wrapper for functionality of the [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class - [source: `capabilities.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L413). After taking a look at the [`get_data_by()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L548) method of the `WP_User` class you will see there is no hook available.

You did not write what you are trying to do. Maybe you can achieve what you want by simply overriding `get_user_by()`. Another possibility could be to additionally `extend` the `WP_User` class. I really can't say much more with the given information, but this should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Not working for me, I have updated the OP again with some more information